# Icons not loading properly when opening website on a specific page on safari

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm encountering an issue with icon and font loading in my Quasar application when viewed on Safari, specifically when opening the site on a particular page. Icons are not displaying as expected. I'm looking for guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this issue.
All the fonts and icons load properly when accessing the application from any rout except "/camera/:id", when entering the site from any other route everything loads properly

Safari version: 17.0

Quasar version: 2.13.0

Vue version: 3.0.0

Example of how I'm using the icons:

```js
<RouterLink :to="`/camera/${$route.params.id}/settings`">
  <q-icon
    class="bg-accent box-shadow q-pa-sm rounded-corners text-primary"
    size="sm"
    name="fa-solid fa-cog"
  />
</RouterLink>
```

icons settings on quasar.config.js:

```js
module.exports = configure((ctx) => ({
  extras: [
    // 'ionicons-v4',
    // 'mdi-v5',
    // 'eva-icons',
    // 'themify',
    // 'line-awesome',
    // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

    'fontawesome-v6',
    'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
    'material-icons',
    'material-symbols-rounded',
    'material-symbols-outlined',
    'material-symbols-sharp',
    'material-icons-outlined',
    'material-icons-round',
  ],
})
```

app.scss

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins;
  src: url('fonts/Poppins-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

routes.ts

```js
{
  path: '/camera/:id',
  component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
  children: [{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/Cam.vue') }],
},
```

The texts and icons remains missing for a long time initially when entering from the problem route

[Initial loading when entering from "/cameras/:id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP2u8.jpg)

[After loading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nTDe.jpg)

[Page that works properly "/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umi09.jpg)

[Problem page "/camera/:id" when entered from "/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPVb1.jpg)

I tried adding the material icons import on the index.html and app.scss but it dindn't work